# Highchart Pie Chart click on hover

Tags: jquery, highcharts, pie-chart

How can I call mouse click event on pie chart on mouse hover?
I tried something but it do click not so smoothly as I need.
Here is code sample:

```
   plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: '50%',
            size: 100,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: false
        },
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Coordinates',
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function (e) {
                      pieChart.tooltip.hide();
                        var serie = this.series.data[this.x];
                        var waitBeforeSelect = setTimeout(function () {
                            clearTimeout(waitBeforeSelect);
                            serie.select();
                            serie.series.show();
                            pieChart.tooltip.refresh(serie);
                        }, 500);

                        var serieName = serie.name;
                        var textToShow = serieName.substr(0, serieName.indexOf(';'));
                        $('#pieChartInfoText').children().text(textToShow);
                        $('#pieChartInfoText').children().css('color', serie.color);
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        pieChart.tooltip.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are really trying do do is simply select the point on mouseOver (what I needed to do that led me to your question), you can call this.select(true) in your mouseOver function. This doesn't have the timeout delay, but that could still be added.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Igor!

Yes, it helped me a lot but it as my own has some drawbacks: if you move the mouse over chart multiple times it will repeatedly go back and forth, it especially is visible on `Donut` chart.

Here is the code snippet:

```
series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Coordinates',
            point: {
                events: {
                    mouseOver: function (e) {
                        var serie = this.series.data[this.x];
                        if ((undefined == previousSerie) || (serie != previousSerie)) {
                            var point = this;

                            if (!point.selected) {
                                pieChart.tooltip.shared = true;

                                var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                                    clearTimeout(timeout);
                                    point.firePointEvent('click');

                                    pieChart.tooltip.shared = false;
                                    pieChart.tooltip.refresh(point);
                                }, 700);
                            }

                            var serieName = serie.name;
                            var textToShow = serieName.substr(0, serieName.indexOf(';'));
                            $('#pieChartInfoText').children().text(textToShow);
                            $('#pieChartInfoText').children().css('color', serie.color);
                            previousSerie = serie;
                        } else {
                            previousSerie = serie;
                        }
                    },
                    mouseOut: function () {
                        //  pieChart.tooltip.hide();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```